# I need to do a bulk password change in Powershell

Tags: powershell, office365, change-password

I have a script that appears to work for the domain but does not seem like it is changing on the (Office 365) side.

```
$UN1 = "user1", "user2", "user3"
$PW1 = "pw1", "pw2", "pw3"
for ($itm=0; $itm -le 135; $itm++){
Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity $UN1[$itm] -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $PW1[$itm] -Force)
Set-ADUser -Identity $UN1[$itm] -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true
Write-Host $UN1[$itm], $PW1[$itm]
}
```

I have also tired running a sync command

```
Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType Delta
```

Comment: Try `Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType Initial` to force a Full sync first. Then after a couple of minutes, do the `Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType Delta`